# Dynamically set properties using ANT

Tags: build, ant, scripting

**Current situation**

I have a *build.xml* containing the following

```
<property file="../build.properties" />
```

and some targets using those properties.

The *build.properties* contains the following

```
build_item1=item1
#build_item2=item2
build_item3=item3
....
build_item10=item10
```

**Desired situation**

I'm trying to modify the *build.xml* so I can dynamically define the properties from the *build.properties* file.
I already have a SELECT query on a database that returns the following:

```
ITEM1    
ITEM3
ITEM10

3 rows selected.
```

Would anyone be able to translate this logic into ANT scripting? (or at least point me in the right direction)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can run your SQL queries from ANT (that's something I've never tried), then the only critical point to remember is this: first definition wins.

That means that you need to perform the query and set properties first, then include your properties file. If you did the reverse, the query results could not override the properties file definitions, because they'd come after.

Comment: I did find a way to run the SQL query from ANT, but I did not find a way to save the output into properties.

Comment: You could save the query output to a file, and then execute a script that converts the results into a properties file, and then use that properties file.

Comment: That was indeed the approach that helped me solve this issue. Thanks!